# why is my jquery change event not firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey so I am trying to target all the elements in my page with a certain class. I am having an issue getting the query change function to fire. So I've tried a number of things and still it's not firing. It will fire at the very start when I load the page but never after it and I get an error message saying that 'this' does not have a change function. However when I log the what this is it clearly shows it's a checkbox. Anyways any help would be appreciated as this should be a very easy thing to do and I imagine I'm missing something small.

```
     $(".rcbCheckBox")
            .each(function () {
                    console.log(this);
                    this.change(console.log("Changed"));
                });
        });
```

Comment: `this` is a reference to the scope in JS, not the element... which will be: `$(this)`

Comment: Cool... beyond that though it still won't fire when I change the checkbox after loading?

Comment: try `$(document).on("change", ".rcbCheckBox", function(){ your code });` because your code isn't listening to any event...

Comment: Always provide explanation of what the code is supposed to do. It's not clear if you are trying to add a change listener or trigger a change event. Broken code is not a good substitute for a proper explanation. When in doubt...read the api docs http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: my explanation is very clear by the code. I want it to print to console every time it's changed. I don't see why I got 2 down votes seeing as I still haven't a solution.

Comment: @Seamy `.rcbCheckbox` is a check box?. I wanna know.

Comment: Yes it is a checkbox. I fixed it by targeting it's wrapper. Basically it's a telerick checkbox and it wouldn't allow me to target the checkbox with a .change event so I had to target it with a .click event. It does what I want now anyway so thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling `this.change` which will return `undefined`, because `change` is a jQuery function. To get this to work use:

```
$(this).change(function(){console.log(this)})
```

Comment: So it's still not firing more than one time... again it's only firing when I load the page but never when I change the checkbox?

Comment: you need to pass a function as an argument to the change method.

Comment: Ya I tried that and it still won't fire. It's really wrecking my head.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(".rcbCheckBox")
        .each(function () {
                console.log($(this));
            });
    });
```

Use $(this) instead of this.

Demo : https://jsbin.com/niqefe/2/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: So it's still not firing more than one time... again it's only firing when I load the page but never when I change the checkbox?

Comment: I made some demo : Check this bin once hope this helps : https://jsbin.com/niqefe/2/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: `$(this).change(console.log("Changed"));` doesn't make sense

Comment: I just added the $(this) but not the actual implementation. you can check the demo which I have added for a sample

Comment: Proper code should be in answer , not demo. Answer should be self contained and demo only used for support of what is in answer

Answer (score 0):

The [change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) function is part of jQuery's API.
Plain DOM objects do not include jQuery's functions. You can create a new jQuery object passing a DOM object to the jQuery funcion:

```
var checkbox = jQuery(this);
```

Or, by short:

```
var checkbox = $(this);
```

Also, your code passes as handler for the `change` event what `console.log("Changed")` returns, which is not a function.

You should do something like this

```
$(this).change( function(){ console.log("Changed"); });
```

Also, look out for a syntax error. You have an extra `});` in your example. Considering all mentioned before, you could try something like:

```
$(".rcbCheckBox").each(function () {
    console.log(this);
    var checkbox = $(this);

    var callback = function(){
        console.log("Changed");
    }

    checkbox.change(callback);
});
```

Comment: So it's still not firing more than one time... again it's only firing when I load the page but never when I change the checkbox?

Comment: @charlietfl, well if you need to log the objects to the console before the event binding, I think using `each` is the way to go.